# Checkbox to url and url to python in Django

Tags: python, django

I've only been coding for 2 weeks but I'm trying to learn Django, Python and HTML to make my first website. (Please forgive me if my question is phrased badly, this is my first ever question)

I have a model which contains booleans that form a list of checkboxes:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    cells = models.BooleanField(blank=True) 
    stainingtechniques = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    enzymes = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    disease = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

I then want to generate some information on a page based on the topics the user has chosen from above. I'm not sure how to do it, but one idea i've had is to create a url/slug that contains the topic names, e.g if they check the checkbox for cells and enzymes but not stainingtechniques then submit, it sends them to /cells-enzymes. Then at the /cells-enzymes page, a code checks if cells or stainingtechniques or cells or enzymes or whatever is in the url and displays info on that page accordingly.

My main question is how can i redirect a user to the the slug of "/cells" if the "cells" boolean is true? / checkbox is checked. At the same time could I send them to /cells+enzymes if they check both but not staining techniques? (what would i need to add to the models.py, views py, urls py)
Then is there a way in python of checking what is present in the url? (In order to say, ok cells is in the url, so lets display the cells info)

Alternatively im open to any other ideas of how to achieve the aim i described above.

Thank you in advance, nicky (i understand if these questions were phrased so badly it is unanswerable)

Comment: Do you have a submit button or done button, which can send the check box data to backend from html? Or do you want this to happen as soon as a checkbox is checked/enabled?

Comment: there will be a lot more topics than two, so i suppose the first option, say the person could check the first and third topics and not the second, then click the submit button it would 'return' (/or in other words update the url user is send to) that the first and third had been checked, which wouldn't be possible with the second option I think (I should have made it clear there would be more than two topics) i've updated the main q to reflect this better

Comment: He's asking if you want this done through ajax, or through a form (with submit button). Seems like you want it done through a form. You can send selected values to your views.py, then process it and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding of your question is that you want to generate different URL's for people based on their checkbox input, and accordingly take them to different URL(served by different view functions?)

So lets assume you have checkboxes in HTML in the following format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="cells" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="enzymes"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="disease" />
```

You can accordingly write code in `views.py` to get the ticked checkboxes from POST request after the form has been submitted like this:

```
checkboxes_selected = request.POST.getlist('options[]')
```

where `checkboxes_selected` will be a list containing all selected checkboxes. If a user selected only cells and enzyme, `checkboxes_selected` will look like `['cells','enzymes']`.You can then generate a URL by doing something like:

```
url = '/'+'-'.join(checkboxes_selected)
```

which would in that case generate a url like `/cells-enzymes` which you can redirect to after a submit from the views by doing `HttpResponseRedirect(url)`. You can map dynamic url's to pages and generate them based on the URL. You will find more about the same [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi this sounds almost exactly what I want, but i'm having trouble understand how it works exactly, say i have the checkboxes, how do i submit the form so that the views.py can handle/use the information from the POST request? (so at the moment, theres checkboxes, you select them, but nothing happens because there is no submit button)

Comment: I think you are still not completely clear with your django concepts. I would suggest going through some short tutorial before you try to deep dive into making websites. I would suggest: [tango with django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/) or [mastering django](http://masteringdjango.com/django-book/)